# CentOS 7 / Apache 2.4 ServerAlias strange behavior

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, serveralias

I am facing a strange problem. I recently set up a fresh CentOS7 minimal install with an apache 2.4 server to replace an older server (CentOS5 / Apache 2.2) in production.
However, when I copied the Vhosts config from the old server to the new, I noted that when I did "httpd -S", the output did not show the aliases, **BUT** the server **IS** answering all the expected aliases...

I tried to test both IP based and name based Vhosts to no avail.

I made exactly the same steps on another server I need to replace, and the behavior between the old server and the new one.

I also compared the apache confs between the 2 new servers (httpd.conf, ssl.conf and the vhosts conf), they are identical.

Expected output:

```
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server vhost.company.com
         port 443 namevhost vhost.company.com
                 alias alias1.company.com
                 alias alias2.company.com
                 alias alias3.company.com
```

Actual output:

```
 *:443                  server vhost.company.com
```

What on earth could cause this difference between two Apache servers?

Thanks for your expertise!

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question.

Comment: Hmm.. You are right! 
In fact i'm a little lost, what could cause this behavior? Why are my vhosts not appearing in the list but still answering?

Thanks!